# Using conditionals in a z/OS makefile

Tags: makefile, mainframe, zos

I have been successfully using [z/OS make](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxa500/make.htm) to build my application. I have now come to point in my project where I move from a debug version of the application to a "release" version, a.k.a non-debug, so my compile options and link options change.

I have been trying to use conditionals in my makefile to mean I don't have to change multiple lines in the file in order to switch between the two build modes, but I cannot find **ANY** examples of conditionals in z/OS make, and the small amount of documentation in the manuals about them is not enough to actually discover how to make it work. I'm hoping someone on here has managed to make them work (no pun intended) and can enlighten me.

Here's what I would like to have (snippet from makefile):-

```
BuildType=DEBUG

.IF ($(BuildType)==DEBUG)
CompOpts= -c -W"c,debug,LP64,sscomm,dll" -D_DEBUG
.ELSE
CompOpts= -c -s -W"c,LP64,sscomm,compress,dll"
.END
```

Note that I understand there are many different ways to set `BuildType`. This snippet has it set in-line for simplicity of asking the question. The problem at hand is the syntax of the `.IF` statement. I cannot make the `.IF` statement work. That's what I am hoping for help, or working examples of.

I have managed to get something working where I only have to edit one character in the file to switch between the two modes, but it is not by any means ideal. N.B. `ANYTHING` is not set to any value in the makefile.

```
# In the .IF clause below, if you have != it will run the DEBUG build
# and if you have == it will run the RELEASE build
.IF ($(ANYTHING)==$(NULL))
CompOpts= -c -W"c,debug,LP64,sscomm,dll" -D_DEBUG
.ELSE
CompOpts= -c -s -W"c,LP64,sscomm,compress,dll"
.END
```

Comment: POSIX-conforming `make` draws macro definitions from the command line, from the environment variable `MAKEFLAGS`, and directly from the environment, in addition to from the makefile's contents (and that's the precedence order, from greatest to least).  I'm uncertain about z/OS `make`'s features, but if it accepts macro definitions from any of those alternative, higher-priority sources then you can use that to override the value of your `BuildType` macro at build time, without altering the makefile at all.

Comment: Are you beholden to z/OS Make? The ported Make from Rocket Software is more flexible

Comment: @JohnBollinger - from your answer I think maybe my question is not clear enough. It's not the setting of BuildType that is the issue, it is the syntax of the `.IF` statement. I will update the question text to clarify.

Comment: @meat - given that it works for everything else I have used it for, I'd rather just find someone who has used a conditional successfully in z/OS make rather than start over with another make. And also, "use another make" is not really an answer to the question at hand for anyone else who might need it in the future.

Comment: I may be completely wrong because I do not know anything about z/OS make, except what I read in the _Conditional expressions_ part of the documentation, but could it be that the expressions in conditionals shall not be enclosed in parentheses (a difference with GNU make)? If I am right you are comparing strings `(DEBUG` and `DEBUG)`...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet - you were indeed correct - it was the extra brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following syntax should work with z/OS make:

```
.IF $(BuildType) == DEBUG
CompOpts= -c -W"c,debug,LP64,sscomm,dll" -D_DEBUG
.ELSE
CompOpts= -c -s -W"c,LP64,sscomm,compress,dll"
.END
```

When you invoke the make file with:

```
make -DBuildType=DEBUG
```

it will select the debug version of compiler options, otherwise it will select the production version.

Comment: That was it - the extra brackets were what was scuppering me! Many Thanks.